# FM Transmitter for the Home

Tags: audio, music, streaming, radio

After asking [this question regarding piping music through my home](https://superuser.com/questions/111325/streaming-music-throughout-the-house-on-a-budget) I'm looking to buy an FM transmitter.

I'd like to connect it to my home pc (ie. into the speaker port), and I'd then control the output with my iPhone (ie. using Apple's Remote software).

The problem is, given that almost every FM transmitter is advertised to be used in the car (ie. an iTrip) it's proving very tricky knowing which one would be ideal for the home.

First, has anyone tried this? Did it work ok or was there simply to much interference for it work.

Secondly, if it did work ok, can anyone recommend a reasonable transmitter?

For what I need it seems like an ideal solution, so given that I'm struggling to find information regarding it I'm starting to believe it's not as ideal as it first seems.

Thanks in advanance.

Comment: note fm transmissions are heavily regulated in most of the world; wikipedia's article indicates current UK regulations may limit power output of a personal transmitter to 50 nanowatts (range of up to 8 meters): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FM_transmitter_(personal_device)#UK_legality_developments

Answer (score 1):

By using [this link](http://www.google.com/search?q=FM+transmitter+for+home) I found this "[Whole Home FM Transmitter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007ODOMA)" at Amazon.  The people who make it have a web page [here](http://www.wholehousefmtransmitter.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Believe me when I say I have googled this. I saw that one but unfortunatly I can't seem to find it in the UK. Which is a shame as it looks ideal. Another one (USB FM Transmitter) also looks good but again I can't find it online for the UK. And appologies I should have stated in the question that I'm in the UK. Thanks again for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: wow.  offers a whole 7 stations to broadcast on.

Answer (score 0):

An older [slasdot article](http://slashdot.org/article.pl?sid=05/01/07/035258) from 2005 have several comments recommending [C.Crane FM transmitter](http://www.ccrane.com/radios/fm-transmitters/fm-transmitter.aspx) (the one I found on their web site is possibly a newer product?).
It transmits 250 µV/meter @ 3 meters (max FCC unregulated), in stereo and uses PLL. So it seems comparable to the "Whole House FM-Transmitter" already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I found another option, [Aareff FM Transmitter 50mW Stereo](http://www.aareff.com/50mwsb.htm). Aareff Systems Ltd is a UK Company their web page says.

Comment: Thanks hlovdal. There were some warnings on their site regarding use in the EU, so I've emailed the company for some additional info and to see whether what I'd like to do is possible in the UK.